# Elasticsearch - Tokenizer configuration

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

Someone have any idea of what tokenizer to use and how to enable rule for the below,

Input : ["test1-data.example.com", "test2-new.example.com", "new1-test.example.com"]

Output (expected ) :
   test1-data.example.com test2-new.example.com new1-test.exampl.com

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious whether it solves your problem or not, but here's one way you can do what it sounds like you're asking:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "_all": {
            "enabled": true,
            "store": true,
            "index": "not_analyzed"
         },
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "include_in_all": true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "text_field": ["test1-data.example.com", "test2-new.example.com", "new1-test.example.com"]
}

POST /test_index/_search
{
    "fields": [
       "_all"
    ]
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "_all": "test1-data.example.com test2-new.example.com new1-test.example.com "
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code in Sense:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/45200711a41268634439b669e18541e68042ac8a

Comment: I tried the above example. but Output doesn't come as like above you mentioned. This is the one I'm getting. 

{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "_all": null
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

Comment: You probably didn't update your mapping with the one I showed.

Comment: I didn't add/remove anything from the example that you shown above. Just I cut and paste on my local setup , then run it. But didn't get an expected output.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I did the same thing, and it produced the output I listed.